# OSX bash script works but fails in crontab on SFTP

Tags: macos, bash, cron, sftp

this topic has been discussed at length, however, I have a variant on the theme that I just cannot crack. Two days into this now and decided to ping the community. THx in advance for reading..

Exec. summary is I have a script in OS X that runs fine and executes without issue or error when done manually. When I put the script in the crontab to run daily **it still runs** but it doesnt run all of the commands (specifically SFTP).

I have read enough posts to go down the path of environment issues, so as you will see below, I hard referenced the location of the SFTP in the event of a PATH issue...

The only thing that I can think of is the IdentityFile. NOTE: I am putting this in the crontab for my user not root. So I understand that it *should* pickup on the id_dsa.pub that I have created (and that has already been shared with the server)..

I am not trying to do any funky expect commands to bypass the password, etc. I dont know why when run from the cron that it is skipping the SFTP line.

please see the code below.. and help is greatly appreciated.. thx

```
#!/bin/bash
export DATE=`date +%y%m%d%H%M%S`
export YYMMDD=`date +%y%m%d`
PDATE=$DATE
YDATE=$YYMMDD
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
FEED="~/Dropbox/"

USER="user"
HOST="host.domain.tld"

A="/tmp/5nPR45bH"

>${A}.file1${PDATE}
>${A}.file2${PDATE}

BYEbye ()
{
rm ${A}.file1${PDATE}
rm ${A}.file2${PDATE}

echo "Finished cleaning internal logs"
exit 0 
}


echo "get -r *" >> ${A}.file1${PDATE}
echo "quit" >> ${A}.file1${PDATE}

eval mkdir ${FEED}${YDATE}
eval cd ${FEED}${YDATE}


eval /usr/bin/sftp -b ${A}.file1${PDATE} ${USER}@${HOST}

BYEbye
exit 0
```

Comment: You are doing a hard work for a temp file, keep it simple with maketmp (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/mktemp.3.html)

Comment: `eval` is complex and dangerous, don't use it when you don't need it. Here you don't need it, so remove it; you do need to change `FEED="~/Dropbox/"` to `FEED=~/Dropbox`. Replace `A="/tmp/some_fixed_name"` by `A="$(mktemp)"`. (These aren't the cause of your problem.) Is there a passphrase on the key? If there is, how do you expect `sftp` to obtain it?

Comment: ... also, why do you use that insane number unneeded "eval" commands. My first advice would be that you should simplify your script removing redundant or unnecesary complicated stuff.

Comment: the eval on the FEED is only needed because the *real* directory structure has spaces.. and the \ was causing problems.. No question I dont write code that is poetry.. so the tmp files stuff was from coding a LONG time ago.. To you point about SFTP and the passphrase, that is an excellent question.. and maybe and hopefully the heart of the solution. When run in terminal, the script works as written above without issue, error, OR interaction. There are no password or passphrases that are needed. My intention is to have the same in the cron. The script executes but skips the SFTP line.

Comment: @Matt, what evidence do you have that the sftp command is skipped? Merely the absence of files? Do you get any error messages in the cron email?

Comment: the absence of files is the most clear part.. but if I have the script do something before the sftp it work.. (like making the directory).. likewise, if I move the delete to the end, it also works.. it is purely the SFTP. Now something that Gilles mentioned (passphrase) made me think also in relation to the environment issues that normally plague cron scripts. I updated the passphrase to blank. It works now in the cron. I have 2 articles that I need to digest on how to get my passphrase to be pickedup inside of the cron when the passphrase is not blank. Ideas?

Comment: here are the articles.  http://help.github.com/ssh-key-passphrases/     
http://oceanpark.com/notes/howto_ssh_keychain_public_key_authentication_forwarding.html

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, just comments about your code.

- The way to handle filenames with spaces is to quote the variable: `"$var"` -- `eval` is not the way to go. Get into the habit of quoting *all* variables unless you specifically want to use the side effects of not quoting.
- you don't need to `export` your variables unless there's a command you call that expects to see them in the environment.
- you don't need to call `date` twice because the YYMMDD value is a substring of the DATE: `YYMMDD="${DATE:0:6}"`
- just a preference: I use `$HOME` over `~` in a script.
- you never use the "file2" temp file -- why do you create it?
- since your sftp batch file is pretty simple, you don't really need a file for it:

  `printf "%s\n" "get -r *" "quit" | sftp -b - "$USER@$HOST"`

---

Here's a rewrite, shortened considerably:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
FEED_DIR="$HOME/Dropbox/$(date +%Y%m%d)"
USER="user"
HOST="host.domain.tld"

mkdir "$FEED_DIR" || { echo "could not mkdir $FEED_DIR"; exit 1; }
cd "$FEED_DIR"
{
  echo "get -r *"
  echo quit
} | 
sftp -b - "${USER}@${HOST}"
```